# Consider a cube of ice with volume equal to 3cm³ and a fixed density equal to 916g/cm3, How many of the molecules are in the surface of the cube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density, molecules, volume, ice

This was a question that my fluid mechanics teacher ask today in class, I find the number of total molecules, and then my teacher says that we could search the size of one $\rm H_2O$ molecule, then I assume that the molecules are arranged in a hexagon shape, like a honey bee cell, then I found how many hexagons are in one side of the cube, then I try to find how many vertices are in the arrangement because the molecules are just that vertices, but are totally insane! Anyone can help me with some ideas or advice? I don't ask to do this for me, I really want to find a way for my self, but I give it all my day and that's all I can get. Thank you very much guys, I'm new to Reddit, but I will try to help you any time. Thanks, my head is burning haha.

Comment: I suggest you estimate it using a simple model, and then for added thoroughness provide also a statement of the precision of your estimate. Around 20% precision is probably easy to achieve, and after that it gets much more difficult.

Comment: This is one of those problems where, assuming you have a good teacher, your grade should be based on **how** you approach the problem, rather than on what the final number calculated is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer can only be a rough estimate, as it's even difficult to define the exact meaning of "in the surface of the cube", given that the ice crystal structure probably doesn't align with the cube's surfaces.

From ice density (by the way, 913g/cm3 should probably read 0.913g/cm3), we can compute the average volume occupied by one molecule and its average size as the cubic root of this volume.

Then it makes sense to define the "surface" of the ice cube as a thin layer with a thickness of the molecule size, allowing us to convert the surface area to a volume, and to compute how many molecules fit into that volume.

In this reasoning, there are a lot of assumptions and weakly-defined terms, e.g.:

- The average density of ice doesn't change at its surface.
- Molecules don't align differently at the surface, so the average molecule size can be taken as the thickness of the "surface".